# what is publication number for US5803169?

Tags: uspto

In reference to the patent: [US5803169](https://www.google.com/patents/US5803169)

Whether this patent was published as application?

Comment: Please provide some additional details. I'm unclear on what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Said Patent application publication number was not issued by USPTO, seems it was published directly as Patent.

source:- file history at public PAIR.